# Is weak, uniformly bounded operator of semigroup also strong?

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

We define strong generator of the semigroup $P_t$ as

$ A f := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{P_tf-f}{t}$ if the limit exists and is in $C_0$

and weak generator of semigroup $P_t$ as

$ A_w f(x) := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{P_tf(x)-f(x)}{t}$ if the limit exists and is in $C_0$ (Pointwise limit).

If also we assume, that operator $\frac{P_tf(x)-f(x)}{t}$ is uniformly bounded, then is it true that $A_w = A$?

Comment: What mean : the limit exist and is in $C_0$ **pointwise** ?